# Typescript vue Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have already checked the questions of the past, but I could not find a solution that worked for me.

I am using Vue Typescript:

```
export default Vue.extend({

    data() {
      return {
        ...
        selectedOrder: null,
      };
    },



approveOrder() {
        if(this.selectedOrder !== undefined && this.selectedOrder!==null && this.selectedOrder !== '') {
          let uri = 'http://localhost:8081/v1/order/approve/';

          uri = uri + this.selectedOrder.processInstanceId + '?approverId=' + this.getUser;
```

Error I get is:

```
164:21 Object is possibly 'null'.
    162 |           let uri = 'http://localhost:8081/v1/order/approve/';
    163 |
  > 164 |           uri = uri + this.selectedOrder.processInstanceId + '?approverId=' + this.getUser;
        |                     ^
```

Comment: why not `selectedOrder: ''`?

Comment: then I get error: `property 'processInstanceId' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Comment: maybe `this.selectedOrder.processInstanceId.toString()`

Comment: no, still `Property 'processInstanceId' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u are not using using the advantages of typescript, i guess you should set any type to your `selectedOrder` object, you could try as bellow:

```
// selectedOrder.interface.ts
interface selectedOrder {
    processInstanceId: Number;
}
```

in your vue component you should to import your interface file, then:

```
// component.vue
export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
      return {
        ...
        selectedOrder: { processInstanceId: 0 } as selectedOrder,
      };
    },
    ...
})
```

Comment: I rather did : ` selectedOrder: {
          processInstanceId: '',
          declineMessage: ''
        },` is that bad? its working this way too

Comment: if you will do it like so then is not neccesary TS.